# Can not update table field onchange of select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I have table structure is like:

```
<table>
<tr class="selected"><th>number</th><td><input type="number"/></td></tr>
<tr><th>name</th><td><input type="text"/></td></tr> ...
</table>
```

I have created textarea and select using reactjs to change `th` and `td` accordingly..
Code:

```
var MySelect = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function() {
                return {
                    value: '',
                    label: ''
                }
            },
            change: function(event){
                this.setState({value: event.target.value});                  
            },
            textChange:function(event){                    
                this.setState({label: event.target.value});                    
            },
            render: function(){
                if($('.selected').length >0 && $('.selected').find('td').length>0){ var stateValue = {this}; $('.selected').find('th')[0].innerHTML = stateValue.this.state.label; }
                if($('.selected').length >0 && $('.selected').find('td').length>0){ var newTag = <input type={this.state.value}/>; $('.selected').find('td')[0].innerHTML = {newTag} }
                return(
                    <div>
                      <p>Field label</p>
                      <textarea rows="3" cols="30" className="inputControl" id="field_name" onChange={this.textChange}></textarea><br />
                      <br />
                      <p>Field type</p>
                        <select className="inputControl" id="field_control" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>                        
                            <option value="text">Textbox</option>
                            <option value="number">Number</option>
                            <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
                            <option value="radio">Radio</option>
                            <option value="textarea">Textarea</option>
                            <option value="select">Dropdown</option>
                            <option value="multiple">Multiple Choice</option>
                            <option value="date">Date</option>
                            <option value="phone">Phone</option>
                            <option value="address">Address</option>
                            <option value="email">Email</option>
                        </select>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div id="selectOption" style={{display: 'none'}}>
                        <p>
                            Choices
                        </p>
                        <div className="space">
                            <input type="text" className="inputControl" /></div>
                        <div className="space">
                            <input type="text" className="inputControl" /><span> <i className="fa fa-plus-circle icon add"
                                title="Add another choice"></i><i className="fa fa-minus-circle icon remove" title="Delete this choice">
                                </i></span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="space">
                            <input type="text" className="inputControl" />
                            <span><i className="fa fa-plus-circle icon add" title="Add another choice"></i><i className="fa fa-minus-circle icon remove"
                                title="Delete this choice"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                        <p><input type={this.state.value} /></p>
                 </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

textarea is helped to change the `th` field and select to change `td` field..When I select from select option then tag will be change `<p><input type={this.state.value} /></p>` but it shows `[OBJECT OBJECT]` in error line..I want to change `td` according to selected value from select option..Can I do `var newTag = <input type={this.state.value}/>; $('.selected').find('td')[0].innerHTML = {newTag}` in `change:` ?..Am I missing something this? please suggest me..

**UPDATE**
I can change th value but when I click to second td and again first td then it shows old text..

Comment: How do you handle the changes from the textarea??

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo I haven't done it yet..May b for both the way will be same

Comment: Did you see that your JSX is not valid? there's an open <div> missing :( on my side, it works fine, the input TYPE is updated according the select value

Comment: In your code, I don't figure out what is .selected

Comment: Sorry I removed some unnecessary tags that's why...

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo please check my updated question..I was doing it by some js and forgot to put there..Thank you and pleasee help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113714/discussion-between-michael-rasoahaingo-and-debin).

Comment: I don't clearly understand what is the relationship between the jquery part and the rest of the render :(

Comment: What do you want to achieve with **<input type="select">** ?

Comment: have to just change table's td field according to selection from select option @KishoreBarik

Answer (score 0):

So try to implement it with REDUX (a FLUX implementation). You can see the complete doc [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/Motivation.html). There's many tutorials also on [egghead](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux)